# Specific revision pages don't include link to suggested edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, revisions-list

On a [revision list](https://superuser.com/posts/340561/revisions), suggested edits are indicated by a link above the user info box:

[image: Screenshot]

However, if you go to the [specific revision page](https://superuser.com/revisions/340561/4), the link is lost:

[image: Screenshot]

It should probably say "suggested 1 min ago" like the main list, and include the markdown source link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good catch - this will be fixed in the next deploy.